# Angular App - Toggle Between Modes (Demo mode and App Mode)?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've been working on Angular application and I have a weird scenario that I'm trying to come-up with a solution for.

We have an application eg: test.com, that uses multiple restful API's (built by us). Our business wants us to capture dummy response of these rest APIs in a static json files and host those json files in a static folder in our codebase itself.

They want to toggle between application mode that uses real RestFul APIs and demo mode that uses the static json response objects.

test.com - triggers application that uses Restful APIs and test.com/demo triggers application that uses static JSON.

If /demo is not the solution, are there any other solutions.

How do I approach this scenario?

P.S - We don't want to manage 2 different code-bases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of.

(1) Have an attribute on the logged in user that indicates if said user is a test user (`user.test` evaluates to `true`). When you log in as that user, you load the DEMO resources.

(2) If you want to stick with the URL condition, you could use`this.router.url === '/demo'` as your check.

Personally, I prefer (1).

Comment: I was thinking about the same option using an interceptor to handle it.